# Bug in iTunes Connect preventing TestFlight submit

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an issue submitting an app build for review in TestFlight.
(Yesterday, a new version of TestFlight was released in iTunes Connect, this might have caused the issue)

Steps to Reproduce the issue:

1. Log in to iTunes Connect
2. Select the app
3. Go to tab 'TestFlight'
4. Click a build (in this case, 1.0.1)
5. Click the '+' sign next to 'Individual Testers'
6. Select 'Add New Testers'

Expected behavior: screen to enter information of test users
Actual behavior: loading spinner is displayed and web inspector console displays error:

[image: Error console]
[image: Loading spinner hangs]

Anyone else experienced this issue? I can only reproduce it for one of my apps. It seems to be some bug on Apple's part, and I have reported it, but no answer until now :-\

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with iTunes Connect.  I just got an email from Apple about upcoming maintenance:

> On **April 22, beginning at 7:00 a.m. (PDT)**, iTunes Connect and related content delivery services will be unavailable for up to eight hours.  The following services will be affected:
>    - App build upload in Xcode
>    - Application Loader and altool
>    - iTunes Connect
>    - iTunes Connect Mobile
>    - iTunes Producer
>    - Transporter

Maybe wait until after the maintenance is over and try again.